# RabbitMQ with MQTT sends message on connect

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I'm using mqtt-launcher (https://github.com/jpmens/mqtt-launcher) to execute commands when a certain MQTT message with the payload "0" was received.

Here is the config

```
logfile         = '/home/user/mqtt-launcher/logfile'
mqtt_broker     = 'broker'       # default: 'localhost'. If using TLS, this must be set to the domain name signed by$
mqtt_port       = 1883              # default: 1883
mqtt_clientid   = 'mqtt-launcher-1'
mqtt_username   = ''
mqtt_password   = ''
mqtt_tls        = None              # default: No TLS

topiclist = {

    # topic            payload value  program & arguments
    "channel/dostuff" : {
       '0' : [
          '/usr/bin/ssh', 
          '-i', 
          '/home/user/.ssh/privatekey', 
          'user@host',
          'script.sh'
          ]
    }
}
```

Everytime, I start the python script, the shell script is executed twice.

But I want it to execute only once if the MQTT message with the payload "0" is sent.

I made sure the queue which is implicitly created when subscribing was empty before by purging it, then starting mqtt-launcher but still the script is execute twice after the program connected.

When I run `user@localhost:~$ mosquitto_sub -h broker -p 1883 -t 'channel/dostuff' -v -u 'user' -P 'mysecurepassword'` I get `channel/dostuff 0`

I'm not familiar with mosquitto but I think that this means I receive a message, right?

I turned of the retain option, restarted openHAB and RabbitMQ, but still the message is sent. Here is the openHAB mqtt.cfg:

```
broker.url=tcp://broker:1883
broker.user=openhab
broker.pwd=mysecurepassword
broker.qos=1
broker.retain=false
broker.async=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have published a message with the payload `0` and the retained bit set.

This means that when ever a client subscribes to that topic the last message with the retained bit set will be delivered to that client.

You can clear the retained message by publishing a message with the retained bit set and a null payload to the same topic. You can do this with the mosquitto_pub command as follows:

```
mosquitto_pub -t "channel/dostuff" -u 'user' -P 'password' -r -n
```

You should make sure what ever you are using to publish the message normally is not setting the retained bit.

Comment: I'm using openhab, I will check

Comment: I changed the openhab config but still no luck (see my edited answer)

Comment: Have you cleared the existing retained message on the broker?

Comment: Stupid me ... I read too fast. I didn't set a null payload on the new message. I thought it would be enough to send a new message. Now everything makes sense to me. I'll try to fix it once more

Comment: No, the message is held on the broker and can only be removed by publishing a null message (as described in my answer). Even restarting the broker will not clear the message